# WSDL- PHP SOAP HTTP REQUEST

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap, wsdl

Despite being a PHP developer, I'm just now getting my first taste of web services. I was hoping to get a little help, as the book I am using is not much help. One of the companies we are doing business with gave me an WSDL XML document in the format in needs to be in (I'll post a link of it). Due to my inexperience in this particular subject, I'm not really sure what to do. I need to know how to implement the WebService interface between my system and their used car management system. Any help or direction would be so greatly appreciated, and please, don't just send a link to the php manual. I've obviously been there, as it is typically the go-to place for help. I have been reading about the curl which will help me to communicate and transfer http request. To access their system they have given me access and i have to use credentials :

The credentials are:

Group ID

Dealer Number:

User:

Password:

The WebService address is:

http://uvm-aw.bmwgroup.com/awonline/de/service2/SNWebService.php

And the WSDL is:

http://uvm-aw.bmwgroup.com/awonline/de/service2/SNWebService.php?wsdl

So my login request and response will look like this :

Login request :

```
<LoginRequest> 
<user> user </ user> 
<password> pass </ password> 
<corporate_group_id> 101 </ corporate_group_id> 
<dealer_number> 11111 </ dealer_number> 
<dms_id> 12345678 </ dms_id> 
</ Login Request>
```

The answer for success looks like

```
<LoginResponse> 
<token> uiih37 </ token> 
<login_id> 8487292 </ login_id> 
<status> 
<success> true </ success> 
<code> 0 </ code> 
<message/> 
<browserURL/> 
</ status> 
</ Login Response>
```

trying to retrive data from wsdl not working:

```
$reference = array(
    'Credentials' => array('UserName' => '', 'Password' => ''),
    'corporate_group_id => '101',
     'dealer_number' => '11111' , 
     'DMS-ID' => 'A13T2D19'
     );
$client = new SoapClient("http://uvm-aw.bmwgroup.com/awonline/de/service2/SNWebService.php?wsdl");
$result = $client->GetTuDetail($reference);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: What is your question? Not knowing what to do is hardly a valid, concrete programming question here on SO. Even if you have my sympathies as a starter, but you need to say something what you want to learn more about even if it's hard to find words as everything looks new to you.

Comment: Hi @hake sry if you dnt understand my question. As mentioned in my question i have given wsdl link. Using that wsdl link I have to connect and fetch important information such as Vehicles data. So for that i need information how to do that.

Comment: I think if i use curl then it will be easy for me to connect to their systems ?

Comment: curl is not able to deal with WSDL, it's just for HTTP transport. A SOAP client is able to deal with WSDL. It also already covers HTTP transport for you. So there actually is *no use* for curl at default for WSDL/SOAP in PHP. http://php.net/class.soapclient - http://php.net/book.soap - Sidenote: If your PHP installation is configured to use curl for HTTP stream transport, then you actually use curl by using SOAPClient.

Comment: Hi can you please tell me where i am doing wrong i alos use soapclient in the my example in question but not working :(

Comment: You need to refer to the Webservice description and double check you're doing the right things here. You can also contact the vendor of the webservice for your support options. I personally can not tell you what is not working for you because your question misses relevant details to that point. But it's often with SOAP/WSDL that you need some time to get started with it, so the best suggestion I can give you is to read about how it works (try some different service as an example, read the specs, read books about it) and then apply to your scenario. Understanding first normally helps.

Comment: Hi thank you. For description i have postes new topic please check here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776067/connect-to-the-webservice-system-with-authentication-using-curl-php

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't work this way. Please ask a concrete programming question. Do not duplicate your own questions, instead edit your original question and improve it. Restrain for posting personal tutoring and support requests.

Comment: i was asking to you abt help man but its ok even i knw how stackoverflow works...

Comment: If you dont know answer then dont answer and my question was not duplicate check the question again

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple implementation example 
This will help you to start :)

```
//path to wsdl file
$wsdl = 'http://uvm-aw.bmwgroup.com/awonline/de/service2/SNWebService.php?wsdl';

//this will help you to debug 
$options = array('trace' => true);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

//Returns list of available SOAP functions described in the WSDL for the Web service. 
print_r($client->__getFunctions());

//some parameters to send
$params = array();
$response = $client->Login($params);

echo("<pre>"); //to format it legibly on your screen

echo 'RESPONSE <br />';
print_r($response);

echo 'REQUEST HEADERS <br />';
var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders()); //the headers of your last request

echo 'REQUEST BODY <br />';
var_dump($client->__getLastRequest()); //your last request

echo 'RESPONSE HEADERS <br />';
var_dump($client->__getLastResponseHeaders()); //response headers

echo 'RESPONSE BODY <br />';
var_dump($client->__getLastResponse()); //the response
```

Comment: hello stasa thanks for your example ...I only have request response technique in my project..so if you can tell me how to fetch data from wsdl service it will be bigh help as given in my example....i am trying to do in this way but not working ...please check the update question...

Comment: I think its because the SOAP is disabled, use phpinfo() to check if it is listed there.